# Modifications in woocommerce Add Product Page?

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I am using woocommerce for my site. I wanna to add some extra fields in add product page following to SKU, Regular Price, Sale Price.. Extra fields contains default values like 2% or 5%. when user enters Product price it should be calculated with default field values & result should be displayed in another field..

For Example:

1. SKU               : 001
2. Regular Price(Rs) : 100
3. Added Text Field1 : 5%  (5% of 100 = 5)
4. Added Text Field2 : 2%  (2% of 100 = 2)
5. Answer Field      : 107 (100 + 5 + 2)

Note: Answer field should be automatically calculated from values present in Regular Price/Sale Price + added text field1 + added text field2.

How to do this???

I have created fields using following function...

```html
// Display Fields
add_action( 'woocommerce_product_options_general_product_data', 'woo_add_custom_general_fields' );

// Save Fields
add_action( 'woocommerce_process_product_meta', 'woo_add_custom_general_fields_save' );

function woo_add_custom_general_fields() {
 
  global $woocommerce, $post;
  
  echo '<div class="options_group">';
  
  // Custom fields will be created here...
  // Text Field
woocommerce_wp_text_input( 
 array( 
  'id'          => '_text_field', 
  'label'       => __( 'Our Commision', 'woocommerce' ), 
  'placeholder' => '5%',
  'desc_tip'    => 'true',
  'description' => __( 'Commision will be added to Product Actual Price', 'woocommerce' ) 
 )
);
// Text Field
woocommerce_wp_text_input( 
 array( 
  'id'          => '_text_field', 
  'label'       => __( 'Payment Gateway Charges', 'woocommerce' ), 
  'placeholder' => '2%',
  'desc_tip'    => 'true',
  'description' => __( 'Payment Gateway Charges will be added to Product Actual Price', 'woocommerce' ) 
 )
);
  echo 'Selling Price = Your Price + Our Commision + Payment Gateway Charges.';
  echo '</div>';
 
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add below code to your theme's `functions.php` :

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_product_options_general_product_data', 'so28712303_rohil_add_custom_general_fields' );
// Save Fields
add_action( 'woocommerce_process_product_meta', 'so28712303_rohil_add_custom_general_fields_save' );

function so28712303_rohil_add_custom_general_fields() {

    global $woocommerce, $post;

    echo '<div class="options_group">';

        woocommerce_wp_text_input( 
            array( 
                'id'  => 'field_1', 
                'label' => __( '<strong>Extra Field 1</strong>', 'woocommerce' ), 
                'placeholder' => '', 
                'description' => __( 'Please enter a number', 'woocommerce' ),
                'type' => 'number',
                'custom_attributes' => array(
                    'step'  => 'any',
                    'min'   => '0'
                ) 
            )
        );

    echo '</div>';

    echo '<div class="options_group">';

        woocommerce_wp_text_input( 
            array( 
                'id'  => 'field_2', 
                'label' => __( '<strong>Extra Field 2</strong>', 'woocommerce' ), 
                'placeholder' => '', 
                'description' => __( 'Please enter a number', 'woocommerce' ),
                'type' => 'number', 
                'custom_attributes' => array(
                    'step'  => 'any',
                    'min'   => '0'
                ) 
            )
        );

    echo '</div>';

    echo '<div class="options_group">';

        woocommerce_wp_text_input( 
            array( 
                'id'  => 'result_field', 
                'label' => __( '<strong style="color:#239804">Result</strong>', 'woocommerce' ), 
                'placeholder' => '', 
                'description' => __( 'Percentage of Price', 'woocommerce' ),
                'type' => 'number',
                'readonly' => 'readonly',
                'custom_attributes' => array(
                    'step'  => 'any',
                    'min'   => '0',
                    'readonly' => 'readonly'
                ) 
            )
        );

    echo '</div>';

}//so28712303_rohil_add_custom_general_fields

function so28712303_rohil_add_custom_general_fields_save( $post_id ){
    $woocommerce_field_1 = $_POST['field_1']; //Value of Extra field 1
    $woocommerce_field_2 = $_POST['field_2']; //Value of Extra field 2
    $woocommerce_result_field = $_POST['result_field']; //No use of this..you can delete
    $regular_price = $_POST['_regular_price']; //Value of regular price

    if( !empty( $woocommerce_field_1 ) || !empty( $woocommerce_field_2 ) ):
        update_post_meta( $post_id, 'field_1', esc_attr( $woocommerce_field_1 ) ); //Save value of Extra Field 1
        update_post_meta( $post_id, 'field_2', esc_attr( $woocommerce_field_2 ) ); //Save value of Extra Field 2
    endif;
    $result_field   =   ( $woocommerce_field_1 * $regular_price ) / 100 ; //Calculation goes here ...
        //if(empty($woocommerce_result_field))
    update_post_meta( $post_id, 'result_field', esc_attr( $result_field ) ); //Save result here ...
}
```

Let me know if you have any doubt.

**Screen shot :**

[image]

Comment: Extra fields are present in add product page.. But result is not displayed when user enter's product regular price

Comment: Have you clicked on update after adding Regular Price, Extra Field 1 and Extra Field 2 value ?

Comment: answer should be like this--->    Regular Price: 100 Extra Field 1 : 5%(Predefined) Extra Field 2 : 2%(predefined) and Result : 107

Comment: After clicking update it is working fine... Extra fields should be percentage of regular price

Comment: You can modify the code as per your needs. And if you find my answer useful you can accept it. Thanks ..

Comment: $result_field   =   ( $woocommerce_field_1 * $regular_price ) / 100 ;   In this code $woocommerce_field_1 represents which term from add product page

Comment: See my edited answer .. Added comment so that you can understand the code .